# THREE DirectionalLight falling off with distance

Tags: three.js

According to the docs for THREE.DirectionalLight:

> This light will behave as though it is infinitely far away and the rays produced from it are all parallel.

But, I'm finding that as a move an object with THREE.MeshStandardMaterial farther away from the light (but kept at the same relative angle), the intensity of the light decreases. This doesn't seem right to me.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas, antialias: true});
renderer.setPixelRatio(dpr);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 700;

var planeGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(200, 200);
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeom, new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0xff00ff, metalness: 1}));
plane.position.z = -10;
scene.add(plane);

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(-50, 50, 100);
scene.add(light);

var helper = new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper(light, 10);
scene.add(helper);

function update(time) {
  plane.position.x = 200 * Math.sin(time);
  plane.position.y = 200 * Math.cos(time/2);
}

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  update(performance.now() / 1000);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
render();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/86/three.min.js"></script>
```

I expect the plane to be lit the same no matter what position it's in. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `MeshStandardMaterial` and have set `metalness` to  1.

Metals reflect primarily specularly; the diffuse component of the reflection is minimal.

So what you are seeing is the "hot spot" of the reflection. Set the `metalness` to zero, for example, and you will see primarily a diffuse reflection.

Also, when using `MeshStandardMaterial`, you should include an environment  map (`material.envMap`) so there is something to reflect. Materials -- especially metals -- will look much better that way.

three.js r.87